# How to display Cycles procedural materials in viewport?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, 3d-view, procedural

According to the Blender wiki [here](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.78/Viewport), as of Blender 2.78c (or around May 20, 2016), procedural cycles materials should display in the Blender viewport in "Material" mode. Unfortunately, this is not working for me.

Musgrave, Voronoi, Noise, Magic, and Brick textures all refuse to display in the viewport. Checker is the only one that works, and it doesn't shade properly.

Is there some option to enable GLSL for these? Could it be a graphics card issue?

I know there are several questions on here about this, but as of May 20 last year, this feature should be implemented. I am using the latest build of blender off GraphicAll, and am on Windows 7 64 bit.

Here is a screenshot of the result in material mode and my node setup:

[image: Material mode]

Comment: Have you tried a build from blender.org?

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? What graphics card do you have? Are your drivers up to date? What happens when you change viewport to *Material* mode, could you post some screenshots of what it shows, and some images of your material node setup?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos As I mentioned, I am using the latest build of Blender 2.78 off GraphicAll. My graphics card is a Nvidia Quadro 2000, and the drivers are updated. When changing to Material mode, the object gets bright, almost white, but has no texture. I'll append a screenshot to my original post.

Comment: @MasterHolbytla I have not yet, but I had this same issue with an older build of 2.78c.

Comment: Working well on my end, might be a graphics issue. Try one of the official builds from Blender.org or buildbot. Also make sure your object's *Maximum Draw Type* is set to *Textured* and nothing else in the *Properties Window*

Comment: Try a brief UV unwrap.

Comment: You are previewing this in Material Viewport mode, not Textured Viewport?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Just to update, I have it working now on a newer system with a Quadro K2200 card. Same build, same OS (Win 7). I can only assume it was a pitfall of the older card.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by enable node wrangler add ons. I use internal VGA.[image]